# Is it possible to get the card type from Apple pay token?

Tags: applepay, wallet

I want to display the Card type used for apple pay transaction, I know that the card details are not present in Apple pay transaction, but is it possible to figure it out from PAN? or any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I got something, where I get to know that your PAN is used to deduce your card type , so PAN is used as card number instead of the original card number. That's related to a specification form EMV saying applicationPrimaryAccountNumber is used to hide the actual card number from getting printed on your payment receipts.

So applicationPrimaryAccountNumber can be used to deduce the card type.

Hope this helps someone